# Finding $x$ and $y$ with the information that "On exactly half of the days,No more than one student was absent".

Tags: probability, statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions

> Henry recorded the number of students present everyday for a total of $40$ days. Also there are a total of $29$ students. Here is the frequency table:

[image]

Also it is given that,on exactly half of the days, No more than one student was absent. Find the values of $x,y$.

My try: Obviously $1+2+x+10+y+12=40 \Rightarrow x+y=15$. But I am unable to frame other equation. I found cumulative frequencies as:
$1,3,x+3,x+13,28,40.$ But not sure how to proceed?

Comment: Why am I not able to see the image?

Comment: Because you are a new user and might post inappropriate images.  I have added it

Comment: @peterwhy - an alternative idea is that Henry (though not me) did not record anything when no students were absent: perhaps there were $30$ students, and none absent on $8$ days making $x+y=7$ and no way of answering the question.  I prefer your suggestion which then allows the question to be answered by looking at $y+12$.

Comment: @peterwhy, the question actually did not specify it. But $n$ stands for number of students absent and $f$ stands for frequency.

Comment: @Henry I am more confused that each day there are at least $24$ students absent, while also given that, for some days, no more than one student was absent.

Comment: @peterwhy, will the question makes more sense, if $n$ is number of students present?

Comment: If this is the frequency table for the number of students absent (so $n$ is the number of students absent on a given day and $f$ is the frequency for that number of students to be absent), as is implied by the problem statement, then the problem itself is inconsistent with the given assumption.  Please review the question and make sure it exactly reflects the problem statement you were given.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sure I will recheck. Thank you

Comment: @all I edited. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"On *exactly* half of the days, no more than one student was absent", i.e. on exactly $20$ days there were $28$ or $29$ students. This gives $y+12=20$, $y=8$ and $x=7$.